# New iPad camera button

Tags: ios, screen-capture, camera, cocoa

I am trying to draw a button in my iOS app which would look exactly like a button in camera App of the new iPad (like on this [image](http://images.apple.com/ipad/features/images/camera_hardware.png))
Since I don't have the new iPad, I can't check it by my own. But what I want to know is, how does this button look like if the background is dark, and if it is some complicated image behind, not just smooth blurred single color as on their screenshot. If somebody has the screenshots of camera app when background is not so ideal, I would appreciate if you share them. Or maybe somebody has values of colors, gradients, sizes, which are used in this button, then it would also be great to see.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a semi-transparent image. Here's two quick grabs.

Noisy background:

[image: iPad 3 Camera Button with Noisy Background]

Black background:

[image: iPad 3 Camera Button with Black Background]

These images were takes from a third generation iPad running iOS 5.1 (9B176)

Comment: Ok. Now I see. Drawing it with CoreGraphics will be much more difficult than just making a raster image. Thanks a lot for screenshots.